# Does Raspberry Pi 4 worth for hosting a website?

Tags: web-server, pi-4

I want to create a personal website as a freelancer. I was wondering if a raspberry pi 4 (1gb ram) is a good choice. I mean, a host can cost up to 50-100€/year, depends on the performance of the server. A raspberry pi 4 costs about 40€, so it's cheaper than an entire year paid for hosting my website from an online company.

My website only contains information about me and services that I offer to small business and  other freelancers.
I don't think I will have many connections simultaneously. Maybe (I hope) 100-200/day.

Is it worth buying a raspberry to create my website instead of relying on an online service? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Presuming you mean from home, ie., the Pi will be on a consumer ISP based LAN, you should first research *what the requirements and restrictions are for running a server through your ISP.*  Generally, they do not provide static IP addresses, so you will need an additional service for that.  This is the same regardless of what brand of hardware or operating system you want to use.

Comment: @goldilocks yeah, I read about no-ip services to solve the static ip problem...Apart from this, it will be a good choice?

Comment: That depends.  I administer inet servers, so my perspective is a bit skewed by what I already know I am comfortable doing.  If a friend asked me if I thought this was a good idea it would depend on what I know that person is capable of and a bit what they are like...

Comment: ...While it could be a good learning experience, doing that in the context of something that has some greater significance -- namely, keeping your web site online -- taints and complicates it.  I'd recommend you pay for hosting month by month, and try to set up your own server at home with a Pi without the stress of needing to keep it all working all the time.  Once you are satisfied the situation is stable, you can transfer it over.

Comment: @goldilocks yeah, I agree about the fact that it could be a good learning experience..that's one of the reasons why I'm thinking to buy a raspberry.
It must be on 24/24h, but this is not a problem for me. My doubts was only about the performance of a website hosted with a raspberry pi 4.
Thanks for your answer :)